# How to retrieve only the children which meet a criteria using query in a jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, join

So I have a parent Class with two OneToMany child classes one of which have another two One to many child classes and I'm executing the following query:

```
@Query("Select distinct fg "
            + " from FaqGroupEntity fg "
            + " left join fg.names fgn "
            + " left join fg.faqs f "
            + " left join f.content fc "
            + " left join f.tags ft "
            + " where fgn.language.id = :language "
            + " and  (fc.language.id is null or fc.language.id = :language) "
            + " and (ft.language.id is null or ft.language.id = :language)")
    List<FaqGroupEntity> findAllByLanguage(@Param("language") int language);
```

It seems to be doing the query right but it's populating each of the "faq" children with all the values regardless of language.

Here's The FaqGroupEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FAQ_GROUP")
@Getter @Setter
public class FaqGroupEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FaqGroupNameEntity> names;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private List<FaqEntity> faqs;
    
}
```

Comment: The query searches for all `FaqGroupEntity` where the `faqs.tags.language`  is X. You are not applying a filter to any children, only to the very parent. Not sure if you can even filter children with JPA. Hibernate has `@FilterDef` and `@Filter`, but these have to be enabled/disabled on a per use basis on the session

Comment: What I'm wondering is how to also only retrieve the faqs.tag which are equal to that language and not all the tags

Comment: Could you please post your `FaqGroupEntity` ?

Comment: Added on an edit

Comment: It's not possible to filter a ToMany relationship with a query

Comment: How to do it then?

Comment: How to do what? The impossible?